# How to encrypt REST body with openid connect OIDC

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, openid

The big picture is:

- an android application which authenticate user with an external openid provider (such as azure AD)
- a server which expose rest endpoints securized with the validation of the jwt token generated by the openid provider and appendend by the android application on each request

How can I implement encryption of the rest body?

I saw JWE but it seems that it encrypt only the JWT and it's not clear how to implement JWE with an openid external provider.

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to let SSL take care of this for you, as the most widely used and easy to manage encryption standard.

There are special cases where double encryption is used, eg a WorldPay device will do additional encryption of credit card numbers before sending them to the server.

If you have special requirements and need more than SSL, please explain them.